# jquery, how to get the values from a multi select box

Tags: jquery, select, tags

Does anyone know how to get the selected values from a select box that has multiple set.

thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSelectedValues()
{
  $("#selectID").?????
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="selectID" MULTIPLE>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
<a href="javascript:getSelectedValues()>press</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("#selectID").val();
```

From the jQuery API documentation on the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

*The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements. In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method **returns an array containing each selected option.***

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the selected selector

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```
$("#selectID option:selected").each(function () {
            $(this).val(); //this is one of the selected values
          });
```

Comment: $('#selectID option:selected');  To select all the options selected.

Comment: You could do that, but this only gives you the selected elements. How would you extract the values? Using `.val()` would only give you the value of the first match. You would need to loop through the results to create a collection.

Comment: @patrick you would have to use a loop like each or something, so it really depends on what you want to do with the values themselves.  If you go the selector route and use each you let jQuery do the heavy lifting for you, and then you can do what you wish on the options that are selected.

Comment: @Joseph - Yes, but the question was how to get the values. ;o)

Comment: @patrick good point, I've modified my answer to include the looping structure and how to get to the value

Answer (score 1):

`$("#selectID").val()` returns a comma delimited list of selected values.